# move dialog to a compontent in Vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

here's my code:

```
        <v-btn @click="showDialog = true" >
            <v-dialog
                v-model="showDialog"
                max-width="600"
            >
              <v-btn @click="showDialog = false">save</v-btn>
            </v-dialog>
        </v-btn>
```

I know that this is fairly simple code, but I would like to extract whole v-dialog to a component. I don't know how to manage `showDialog`. Should I use prop? I now I shouldn't modify prop from inside of the component. What's the other way?

Answer (score 1):

I've never been a fan of driving the visibility of a dialog with a reactive v-model value. Normally, dialogs need to do *some* amount of setup and state related things before displaying and before hiding.

So, what I do is I move `showDialog` to be a hidden internal value to the component itself, I put a `ref=` on the component, I implement an `open()` method on the component and call that when I want to show it.

This pattern feels more natural when a dialog is performing more complicated tasks than just showing static information.

So in your case:

```
<script id="myDialog" type="text/x-template">
    <v-dialog
        v-model="showDialog"
        max-width="600"
    >
        <v-btn @click="save">save</v-btn>
    </v-dialog>
</script>

[...]

        <v-btn @click="openMyDialog">
            <myDialog ref="myDialog">
            </myDialog>
        </v-btn>
```

On myDialog:

```
    data: function () {
        return {
            [ other attributes ]
            showDialog: false
        }
    },
    methods: {
        [ other methods ]
        open: function (initializationData) {
            [ initialization code ]
            this.showDialog = true;
        },
        save: function (event) {
            [ save code ]
            this.showDialog = false;
        }
    }
```

On the parent component:

```
    methods: {
        [ other methods ]
        openMyDialog: function (event) {
            this.$refs.myDialog.open([ initialization data ]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function as a prop for changing value of the `showDialog` in the another component . ( To avoid getting error `avoid mutating a prop directly` )

`exampleComponent.vue`

```
<template>
  <v-dialog v-model="showDialog" max-width="600">
    <v-btn @click="hideDialog">save</v-btn>
  </v-dialog>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    showDialog : Boolean ,
    hideDialog: Function,
  },
};
</script>
```

`mainFile.vue`

```
<template>
  <example :hideDialog="hideMethod" :showDialog="showDialog"></example>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      showDialog : false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    hideMethod() {
      this.showDialog = false;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```